# Get name of all linkedin connections using selenium and c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

I am automating scenario to send message to all linked in connections which are in my network.

I just noticed that `linkedIn` lazy loading seems not working perfect some time. When there are large number of connections and I click on see all, it is unable to load all the connections most of time and lazy loading stops. So here in my script even I do scrolling, I am unable to get all the connection names.

I have read about some APIs to fetch all the connections but it seems not working when I visit : `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections`. I even tried with basic auth by providing user name and password.

Is there any other way to get all linkedin connection names via automation. I  do not want to export as that is diff. scenario and not useful for now for me.